# Annotation for validation base64 string in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation, javax-validation

I have a rest service with my request body bean annotated with javax.validation like `@NotBlank @NotNull @Pattern` etc., and in one specific field I receive a file encoded as a **string base64**,

so, *is there an annotation, or how could I write a custom validation annotation, so it would check if the string is really a base64 string?*

I just need a validation like this in annotation form:

```
try {
    Base64.getDecoder().decode(someString);
    return true;
} catch(IllegalArgumentException iae) {
    return false;
}
```

thnx in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you could write your own annotations and validators for them.

Your annotation would look like this:

```java
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = Base64Validator.class)
@Target( { ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface IsBase64 {
    String message() default "The string is not base64 string";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Constraint validator `javax.validation` implementation (I'm using here your code for the actual validation):

```
public class Base64Validator implements ConstraintValidator<IsBase64, String> {
    
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        try {
            Base64.getDecoder().decode(value);
            return true;
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Example data class with the annotated field:

```
@Data
public class MyPayload {
    @IsBase64
    private String value;
}
```

And controller method example with `@Valid` annotation which is required:

```
@PostMapping
public String test(@Valid @RequestBody MyPayload myPayload) {
    return "ok";
}
```

**UPDATED**:
Also, if you want to check whether the fiven string is a base64 string, you can use the method `isBase64()` from apache-commons libraby, the class is `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`
So, it would look like this
`Base64.isBase64(str);`

Comment: yes! thnx @kerbermeister, after I post the question I came across this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63373437/custom-validation-with-javax-validation , pretty much your answer, and yes this does works, thnx again dude :)